# selecting array data randomly using spacebars

Tags: arrays, meteor, random, spacebars

I'm using spacebars to generate a pop quiz-style form. The following code correctly displays the details of the 3rd item in the quiz array

```
{{#with quiz.[2]}}
    <form class="testForm">
        <br>
        {{question}}<br>
        {{#each answer}}
        <input type="radio" name="multipleChoice" value={{this}}>{{this}}<br>
        {{/each}}
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        <br><br><br>
    </form>
{{/with}}
```

and the following helper function correctly generates a random number from the number of items in the quiz array

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  randomNumber() {
    return _.random(0, (this.quiz.length - 1));
  }
});
```

now what I'm trying to do is get the

```
{{#with quiz.[2]}}
```

to use that random number generator to randomly display a quiz. Logically I want to do something like

```
{{#with quiz.[randomNumber]}}
```

but that doesn't work obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust your helper a bit to return a random element of the `quiz` array instead of the random number itself:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  randomElement(array) {
    return array && array[_.random(0, (array.length - 1))];
  }
});
```

Then just refer to it as: `{{#with randomElement quiz}}`

Comment: thankyou! that gets me exactly the right result!

I am getting a console error from it though: "Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" -- any thoughs?

Comment: See the updated code that guards against the array being missing which can often happen when a subscription isn't yet ready.